Simple macro for database storage
I have tried to create a macro where I am collecting data from field B2:D3;E2. This data is the minimum, maximum and structure names for a given of tests that excel is doing. Currently my macro is taking the correct data from B2:D3;E2 and storing it on the side (In row S:V). Every time I click my button to activate it, it should find the next available row for the given data, and store it there. But currently it only works once, and if I delete the stored data (The first data in S:V), then I can redo it, so it seems like it cannot find "nextRow"
Here is my code:
    Sub CalculateMinMax()

    Dim inputRange As Range, inputName As Range, resultName As Range, resultRange As Range
    Dim minValues As Range, maxValues As Range
    Dim nextRow As Long

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ' Define ranges
    Set inputRange = Range("B5:D300") ' Adjust as needed
    Set inputName = Range("E2") ' Adjust as needed
    Set resultName = Range("Q2") ' Adjust as needed
    Set resultRange = Range("B2:D3") ' Adjust as needed
    Set minValues = Range("S2:V2") ' Adjust as needed
    Set maxValues = Range("S3:V3") ' Adjust as needed

    ' Find the next available row
    nextRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(minValues.Column) + 2

    ' Calculate minimum values
    For Each cell In inputRange
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            minValues.Cells(nextRow, cell.Column - 1).Value = _
                IIf(minValues.Cells(nextRow, cell.Column - 1).Value = "", cell.Value, _
                    WorksheetFunction.Min(minValues.Cells(nextRow, cell.Column - 1).Value, cell.Value))
        End If
    Next cell

    ' Calculate maximum values
    For Each cell In inputRange
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            maxValues.Cells(nextRow, cell.Column - 1).Value = _
                IIf(maxValues.Cells(nextRow, cell.Column - 1).Value = "", cell.Value, _
                    WorksheetFunction.Max(maxValues.Cells(nextRow, cell.Column - 1).Value, cell.Value))
        End If
    Next cell

    ' Copy name
    For Each cell In inputName
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            maxValues.Cells(nextRow, cell.Column - 1).Value = cell.Value
        End If
    Next cell

    ' Increment nextRow for future calculations
    Set Offset = Range("S2:V3")
    For Each cell In Offset(1)
        If Offset(1) <> "" Then
            Offset(nextRow, cell.colunm - 1).Value 1
            
        End If
    Next cell
    Exit Sub

    ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "An error occurred. Please check the input data and try again."
    End Sub

    Sub TriggerCalculation()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler2
    CalculateMinMax
    Exit Sub

    ErrorHandler2:
    MsgBox "Error triggering calculation. Please check the button assignment and try again."
    End Sub

I tried rewriting the "' Increment nextRow for future calculations", but with no help.
The offset function did not help it.
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Edit:
I am trying to take 7 pieces of data from mass sheets that I am copying in. The 6 pieces is from 3 different tests that we do on site. And the 1 piece is the structure data (Name) See picture below:
Data overview

The blue highlighted text should be copied over to a different place in the sheet, where I can store it. For now I have been able to get the information over (Copying it), but thereafter I can not get it to go 2 rows below and store the next data (In the picture attached the data changes on the data I input into the input.
Data storage area


The column of Range("S2:V2") is the column number for column S that is the integer 19. CountA of 19 is 1 i.e. nextRow = 3.

Could you please elaborate? Where should I implement "nextRow = 3"

My comment was supposed to tell you that the calculation of nextRow is wrong i.e. it will always return 3. I could help you if you could describe in detail what it is you're trying to do e.g. for row 2 and 3. I can't figure it out from your code. Share the clarifications by editing your post.

I have now updated the description. I hope it clarifies a bit.

So you're doing something in the source range B2:D3;E2 and each time you press the button the values should be copied to where? I understand that it has to be below the previously copied data. There are 7 (not 6) cells. Assuming there is no data copied yet, what is copied where to e.g. to B2:D3 is copied to S2:V3 and E2 to X2?

B2:D3 is copied (The first time) to S2:V3, and E2 to U2. Next time I click the button, I would like it to look if S2:V3;U2 is occupied (And it is), then it should say; "Is the next range (S4:V5;U4) occupied? No? Then store the data? Yes? Then look at the next range and see if its applicable.

A more traditional route to determining last used row/first available row would likely work better:
nextRow = Range("S20000").End(xlUp).Row()

or similar `End(xlup/down)
Using counta might look something like
nextRow = WorksheetFunctions.CountA(Range("S:S")) + 3 

Where we count all values in the S column as opposed to counting all values in your S2:V2 range, which will max out 4 making it not useful.
